# ThreeJS switch video texture Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, video, three.js

Hi,
I'm mapping a video texture onto a sphere in ThreeJs. I dynamically changing the source of the video on click to display different videos.

The Code runs and switches the source, but it takes different times on different devices to update. It's kind of a lag. The source is switched and then it takes X-Milliseconds to update to the new video. During that time, the old video keeps playing. So I guess it might be some kind of video memory thing?

---

The lags are like this:

1. Desktop PC Chrome - `instant` exchange
2. Macbook Pro 13 Chrome - `0.2 seconds` lag
3. Nexus 5 Chrome - `0.5 seconds` lag
4. Iphone 7 Safari - `1 second` lag

---

I'm preloading all videos with `preloadJS`, but this still didn't change anything. Using smaller videos on mobile (implemented in the example) also didn't help.

Basically I'm doing this:

```
this.video = document.createElement('video');
this.video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
this.video.muted = true;
this.video.loop = true;
this.video.src = 'img/Room1Mobile.mp4';
this.video.crossOrigin = '';
this.video.play();

this.videoTexture = new THREE.Texture(this.video);
this.videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
this.videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
this.videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

this.sphereMat.side = THREE.BackSide;
this.sphereMat.transparent = true;
this.sphereMat.opacity = 1;

this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(this.cubeGeometry, this.sphereMat);
this.cube.name = "videoGlobe";
this.scene.add(this.cube)
```

Later I then switch the source like this:

```
this.video.src = "img/Room2.mp4";
this.video.load();
this.video.play();
```

I understand, the problem is quite difficult to debug, but still hope someone could give me a tip :)

Here's a full [demo](https://vinzenzaubry.com/stackoverflow/ThreeVideoLoad).

Comment: It's not instant for me on Desktop PC Chrome if i clear the cache (or rather disable it when devtools is open, one of the devtool settings). IIRC mobile browsers will only play one video at a time. It's possible that has something to do with it. On the other hand if you only have a few videos you might consider using multiple video elements instead of one video element. That would at least allow the browser if it wants to to pre-load the videos.

Comment: Now I'm preloading the videos dynamically before I play them and it greatly reduced the loading time of the videos. So I guess, the lag was due the `loading time` for the video to trigger video.play().